# AJAX autocomplete with same input name

Tags: ajax, input, autocomplete

I'm trying to use AJAX autosearch (jquery-ui.min.js )

```
$(function() {  
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2
    });             
});

<input name="data[]" class="auto" type="text" style="width:100px;">
```

I want to have multiple input ajax `auto complete` feature with same input name but only first input working

```
<input name="data[]" class="auto" type="text" style="width:100px;">
<input name="data[]" class="auto" type="text" style="width:100px;">
```

Comment: This code is working on jsfiddle. Any errors showing in the console of the browser?

Comment: yes working but only first input , in fact add new row with javascript so get same name value with up row , i want working autosearch for added in each row

Comment: So if I understand correctly you start with just one input. Can't you assign autocomplete to the newly created input in the JavaScript code that creates the new input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<input name="data[]" class="auto" type="text" style="width:100px;">
<br>
<button id="add"> Add field</button>
```

JS

```
function autoComplete(target) {
    target.autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2});
    target.attr('test','yes');
}

$(function() {  
    autoComplete($(".auto").first());    

    $("#add").click(function() {
        newInput = $(".auto").first().clone();
        newInput.insertAfter($(".auto").last());
        newInput.val('');
        autoComplete($(".auto").last());
    });
});
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4kpnxop/3/) (check the console of your browser to see it posting to search.php)